# What is an example of using OAuth 2.0 and Google Spreadsheet API with Java?

Tags: java, oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

Where is example code showing how to use the `Google Data Java Client Library` and its support for `OAuth 2.0` with the `Google Spreadsheet API` (now called the `Google Sheets API`)?

Comment: Looks good. Maybe add code to get the access token from the refresh token. ... Also would be fitting to convert this into question and answer format.

Comment: Hmm this is an answer masquerading as a question?! ... I think I will restructure this as a Q and A.

Answer (score 7):

Answer moved from original question to match site "Q and A" format.

The `Google Data Java Client Library` supports `OAuth 2.0`.
Unfortunately, there are no complete samples in the library showing how to use it with the `Google Spreadsheet API`.

Here is an example that has worked for me. I hope someone find it helpful.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class NewClass {

  // Retrieve the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET from an APIs Console project:
  //     https://code.google.com/apis/console
  static String CLIENT_ID = "your-client-id";
  static String CLIENT_SECRET = "your-client-secret";
  // Change the REDIRECT_URI value to your registered redirect URI for web
  // applications.
  static String REDIRECT_URI = "the-redirect-uri";
  // Add other requested scopes.
  static List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");


public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, ServiceException, com.google.protobuf.ServiceException{
    Credential credencial = getCredentials();
    JavaApplication20.printDocuments(credencial);
}


  /**
   * Retrieve OAuth 2.0 credentials.
   * 
   * @return OAuth 2.0 Credential instance.
   */
  static Credential getCredentials() throws IOException {
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    // Step 1: Authorize -->
    String authorizationUrl =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, SCOPES).build();

    // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
    System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

    // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
    String code = in.readLine();
    // End of Step 1 <--

    // Step 2: Exchange -->
    GoogleTokenResponse response =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
            code, REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    // End of Step 2 <--

    // Build a new GoogleCredential instance and return it.
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build()
     .setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken()).setRefreshToken(response.getRefreshToken());
  }

  // …
}
```

Here the other Class:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CellEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CellFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
// ...
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
// ...

public class JavaApplication20 {
  // …

  static void printDocuments(Credential credential) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    // Instantiate and authorize a new SpreadsheetService object.

     SpreadsheetService service =
            new SpreadsheetService("Aplication-name");
     service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
    // Send a request to the Documents List API to retrieve document entries.
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
    // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
        SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
     if (spreadsheets.isEmpty()) {
      // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
    }
com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
    System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
// Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
    // TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
    // app's needs.
    WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
        spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

    // Fetch the cell feed of the worksheet.
    URL cellFeedUrl = worksheet.getCellFeedUrl();
    CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

    // Iterate through each cell, printing its value.
    for (CellEntry cell : cellFeed.getEntries()) {
      // Print the cell's address in A1 notation
      System.out.print(cell.getTitle().getPlainText() + "\t");
      // Print the cell's address in R1C1 notation
      System.out.print(cell.getId().substring(cell.getId().lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + "\t");
      // Print the cell's formula or text value
      System.out.print(cell.getCell().getInputValue() + "\t");
      // Print the cell's calculated value if the cell's value is numeric
      // Prints empty string if cell's value is not numeric
      System.out.print(cell.getCell().getNumericValue() + "\t");
      // Print the cell's displayed value (useful if the cell has a formula)
      System.out.println(cell.getCell().getValue() + "\t");
    }

  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: this helped me a lot, thanks you. It should be noted that in most cases you actually want to access the spreadsheet with refresh token rather than access token

Comment: @MosheShaham I think you mean: the access token expires after about 1 hour and you need to get a new access token using the refresh token.

Comment: in android application (installed application) google provides only client ID (don't have client secret). I want to edit a google spreadsheet from my android app, how should I use this example with no Client secret?

Comment: How do you set up the redirect URI, for a desktop application? Your answer is hardly of any use.

Comment: where did you get the application name? I get an exception says "com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)"

Comment: SpreadsheetService do not have setOAuth2Credentials function. I am using gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar. I am stuck at time point. Please help me with finding solution

Answer (score 1):

You can find a step by step explanation with examples [here](http://open-thoughts.net/Article/Read/11). As a result, your code might look like this:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V1); // It's important to specify the version

service.setRequestFactory(makeAuthorization());

SpreadsheetQuery q = new SpreadsheetQuery(new URL(DEFAULT_SPREADSHEET_QUERY));

SpreadsheetFeed feed;
try {
  feed = service.query(q, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
}
catch (AuthenticationException e) {
  refreshAccessToken(service);

  feed = service.query(q, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
}

SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = findSpreadSheet(feed);

...

// do your stuff

...

// a couple of utility methods are used above:

private void refreshAccessToken(SpreadsheetService service) throws Exception {
  String accessToken = callGetAccessTokenApi();

  // save access token

  service.getRequestFactory().setAuthToken(new GoogleAuthTokenFactory.OAuth2Token(new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken)));
}

//private static final String GOOGLE_API_HOST = "https://www.googleapis.com/";

private String callGetAccessTokenApi() throws Exception {
  HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

  String url = String.format(
    "%soauth2/v3/token?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&refresh_token=%s&grant_type=refresh_token",
    GOOGLE_API_HOST,
    googleAuthorization.getClientId(),
    googleAuthorization.getClientSecret(),
    googleAuthorization.getRefreshToken()
  );
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
  post.addHeader(ACCEPT_HEADER_NAME, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    JSONObject object = readJson(response);

    return object.getString("access_token");
  }
  finally {
    post.releaseConnection();
  }
}

private Service.GDataRequestFactory makeAuthorization() {
  Service.GDataRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpGDataRequest.Factory();

  // load access token

  requestFactory.setAuthToken(new GoogleAuthTokenFactory.OAuth2Token(new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken)));

  return requestFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**(Dec 2016)** Much of this question and most answers here are now out-of-date as: 1) [GData APIs](http://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) are the previous generation of Google APIs. While not all GData APIs have been deprecated, [all **modern** Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis) do **not** use [the Google Data protocol](http://developers.google.com/gdata); and 2) Google [released a new Google Sheets API v4](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/05/apps-dev-sheets-api.html) (not GData) in 2016. In order to use the new API, you need to get [the Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java) and use the latest [Sheets API](http://developers.google.com/sheets), which is much more powerful and flexible than any previous API.

Here's [our Java Quickstart code sample](http://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java) to help you get going on using the API -- there's OAuth2 code in it too. Also, here are [the JavaDocs reference for the Sheets API](http://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/) which outlines all the classes at your disposal. If you're not "allergic" to Python, I've also made a video walking through the OAuth authorization code and another pair of videos with more "real-world" examples using the Sheets API:

- [Accessing Google APIs: Common code walkthrough](http://youtu.be/h-gBeC9Y9cE?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=3) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2014/11/authorized-google-api-access-from-python.html))
- [Migrating SQL data to a Sheet](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html))
- [Formatting text using the Sheets API](http://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/formatting-cells-with-the-google-sheets-api.html) (code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/09/formatting-cells-in-google-sheets-with.html))

The latest API provides features not available in older releases, namely giving developers programmatic access to a Sheet as if you were using the user interface (create frozen rows, perform cell formatting, resizing rows/columns, adding pivot tables, creating charts, etc.) Also note this API is primarily for programmatic spreadsheet operations & functionality as described above.

To perform file-level access such as uploads & downloads, imports & exports (same as uploads & downloads but conversion to/from various formats), you would use the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) instead, and here are a pair of examples I've created (also Python):

- (simple) Exporting a Google Sheet as CSV ([blogpost](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html))
- (intermediate) "Poor man's plain text to PDF" converter ([blogpost](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html)) (*)

(*) - TL;DR: upload plain text file to Drive, import/convert to Google Docs format, then export that Doc as PDF. Post above uses Drive API v2; [this follow-up post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) describes migrating it to Drive API v3, and here's a [developer video](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) combining both posts.

To learn more about how to use Google APIs (mostly Python or JavaScript), check out the variety of Google developer videos ([series 1](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq) and [series 2](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJJFx_MVCQJ7eWF3gDxkl)) I'm producing.