# Reading Data from google spreadsheet using java

Tags: java, google-sheets

I am using following code for reading data from spreadsheet but it is not working.

```
    import java.net.URL;
    import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
    import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
    import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
    import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
    import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
    import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

    public class ReadSpreadsheet {
    public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME = "xxxx@gmail.com";
    // Fill in google account username
    public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = "xxxx"; // Fill in google account password
  public static final String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/1L8xtAJfOObsXL-XemliUV10wkDHQNxjn6jKS4XwzYZ8"; //Fill in google spreadsheet URI

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ServiceException
  {
    /** Our view of Google Spreadsheets as an authenticated Google user. */
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");

    // Login and prompt the user to pick a sheet to use.
    service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME, GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);

    // Load sheet
    URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);
    URL listFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0)).getListFeedUrl();

    // Print entries
    ListFeed feed = (ListFeed) service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
    for(ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries())
    {
      System.out.println("new row");
      for(String tag : entry.getCustomElements().getTags())
      {
        System.out.println("     "+tag + ": " + entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
      }
    }
  }
    }
```

I am getting issue is following line:
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");

here I need to write application name in some specific format that I have followed using following link:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService.

but I cannot understand the version format which should be written like "[company-id]-[app-name]-[app-version]"

moreover I am using this code in my selenium script for reading/writing data. so please anyone suggest me the actual solution, also if it is possible to reading/writing data from selenium without using this code than it will be great.

error that I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableTypes(AltFormat.java:399)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableXmlTypes(AltFormat.java:387)
at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<clinit>(AltFormat.java:49)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:558)
at ReadSpreadsheet.main(ReadSpreadsheet.java:21)
```

and I am using following jars in this project:

```
    gdata-core-1.0.jar
    gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
    guava-20.0
    mailapi.jar`
```

Comment: Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25457199

Comment: Is it necessary to use oauth process for fetching data from spreadsheet??, In my current code I am already using my credential so it should not require any more authentication process. please suggest.